# Дополнить код c помощью цикла for

Tags: javascript, строки

Приветствую, помогите дополнить код в скрипте чтобы:

1. первая линия была длиной 10 пикселей.
2. каждая последующая на 10 пикселей больше.

Должна получиться пирамидка-ёлочка из линий.

Вот код:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    function line() {
        document.writeln("<hr align='center' width='100'>");
    }
    for(var i=1; i<=10; i++)         
        line();
</script>
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```js
function line(width) {
  document.writeln("<hr align='center' width='" + width + "0'>");
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  line(i);
```

Comment: _первая линия была длиной 10 пикселей_ - зачем было добавлять процент?

Comment: Невнимательность :)

Comment: Спасибо! А какой код лучше дописать, чтобы продублировать эти пирамиды вниз, чтобы получилась ёлка?

Comment: document.writeln("<hr align='center' width='" + width + "0'>")

Comment: Что в данном случае означает "0" после  "+width+"?

Comment: В цикле i изменяется от 1 до 10. Размер линии должен быть от 10 до 100. Вместо умножения на 10 я просто дописываю 0.

Comment: Для "роста" елки измените i <= 10; до нужного значения, например, 100.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Но в данном случае под "дублированием пирамид"  я имел в виду их повторение так, чтобы они они располагались каждый друг над другом. Одна маленькая пирамида над другой аналогичной пирамидой и т.д.  Какую функцию лучше использовать?

Comment: for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) line(i); Несколько циклов нужно

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно передавать ширину линии параметром и вставлять этот параметр в строку которую нужно выводить.

```js
function line(width) {
  document.writeln(`<hr align='center' width='${width}'>`);
}
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  line(i * 10);
```

Comment: Спасибо! В строке, где width='${width}', что означает "$" и почему фигурные скобки, а не  "+ width +" ?

Comment: Новая возможность: [Шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), с ними удобнее собирать строки, которые используют данные из кода

Answer (score 0):

Наверное так правильнее будет, не `0` добавлять, а умножать на `10` (каждый сл. будет в `10` раз длиннее):

```js
function line(width) {
  document.writeln("<hr align='center' width='" + width*10 + "'>");
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
  line(i);
```

Лично мне вот такой вариант больше нравиться )) :

```js
function line(width) {
  var line = document.createElement('hr');    
  document.body.appendChild(line);

  line.style.width += width*10 +'px';
}

for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  line(i);
}
```